# How do I recover Wampserver MySQL database physical files into a working state?

Tags: mysql, database, file, wampserver, restore

**What I want:**

A procedure to restore my WAMP Server (MySQL 5.7.31) particularly the database to a working state from physical database files.  I have a latest backup copy (dated, but backed up) of the physical files of the database, and the entire MySQL folder.

If a procedure is unavailable, I'd like some guidance as to how get started.

**Here is my first attempt:**

So far I attempted physical copy of my entire former Wampserver installation from the same computer but different computer name, as my computer hardware motherboard was swapped (from the OEM)

**What I did afterwards:**

Attempt using the physical copy transfer of the wampserver gave an error in mysql that indicated a write permission needed to be changed in ibdata1.

Modification, by addition of Network Service as a registered full access modifier user of the folder (mysql folder that is) did not change the nature of the error.

**Result:**

Error in mysql logs persist and unfortunately because I uninstalled wamp to try once more differently I am unable to provide the exact error messages pertaining to os write error (I believe error #2 code)

Any suggestions or starting pointers to restore my database and tables would be tremendously appreciated...

### **/mysql5.7.31/data**

- /mysql
- /performance_schema
- /projectaim

  - Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
  - ---
  - -ar---          7/7/2021  11:11 PM             61 db.opt
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   6:45 PM           8806 projectlog.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   6:45 PM             40 projectlog.MYD
  - -ar---         8/25/2021   3:09 PM           1024 projectlog.MYI
  - -ar---         8/25/2021   8:31 PM           8586 projectroles.frm
  - -ar---         8/25/2021   8:31 PM              0 projectroles.MYD
  - -ar---         8/25/2021   8:31 PM           1024 projectroles.MYI
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:48 PM           8614 projects.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:46 PM           9868 riskeventlog.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:46 PM           8944 riskeventlog.MYD
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:46 PM           1024 riskeventlog.MYI
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:40 PM           9611 riskevents.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:49 PM           9435 risklog.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:49 PM           3836 risklog.MYD
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:49 PM           1024 risklog.MYI
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:49 PM          10261 riskmatrixconfigurationlog.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:49 PM             64 riskmatrixconfigurationlog.MYD
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:49 PM           1024 riskmatrixconfigurationlog.MYI
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:49 PM          10261 riskmatrixconfigurations.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   9:51 PM           8682 riskmatrixthresholds.frm
  - -ar---         8/25/2021   7:58 PM           8632 riskroles.frm
  - -ar---         8/25/2021   2:55 AM           9196 risks.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   6:47 PM          12810 usercredentiallog.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   6:47 PM              0 usercredentiallog.MYD
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   6:47 PM           1024 usercredentiallog.MYI
  - -ar---          7/7/2021  11:12 PM          12810 usercredentials.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   6:48 PM           9103 userlog.frm
  - -ar---         8/24/2021   6:48 PM           2604 userlog.MYD
  - -ar---         8/25/2021   3:09 PM           1024 userlog.MYI
  - -ar---         8/23/2021   7:43 PM           9103 users.frm

/sys

- auto.cnf
- ca.em
- ca-key.pem
- clent-cert.pem
- client-key.pem
- ib_buffer_pool
- ib_logfile0
- ib_logfile1
- ibdata1
- ibtmp1
- private_key.pem
- public_key.pem
- server-cert.pem
- server-key.pem

Comment: if you install the **same** wamp server verasion it should be enough to copy **all** the files  into the data folder

Comment: Unfortunately, errors mentioned above persist, and the computer name which changed by means of hardware update was a present event prior to my restoration attempt.  I was on Windows 11 (unclear if this would affect state)  I have downgraded to Windows 10.

Comment: I will make a fresh attempt to install the same wamp server version, and copy the enire mysql directory

Comment: if there is an error show the log, but it usually works

Comment: I might need to find a 3rd party recovery tool to recover the schema and produce a importable SQL export script

Comment: Whqat show the error log? after installation and running the databse for the first time, you can copy but search the internet for recvery from files mysqql and you find a lot of solutions